# Easy way to add a Label to the WPF ComboBox control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, custom-controls

This code is becoming more common in my application:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label Content="_ComboBox Caption" 
           Target="comboBox" 
           Margin="0" 
           Padding="5,5,5,1" />

    <ComboBox  x:Name="comboBox"
                Width="72"
                Margin="5,0,5,5"
                Padding="5,1,5,5"
                SelectedItem="{Binding ComboSelectedItem}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ComboSourceList}" />
</StackPanel>
```

It renders me a Captioned ComboBox.

I would like to make me a custom control that is a ComboBox that exposes the Label's content and then sets the other properties up.  Something that could be used like this:

```
<Controls:CaptionedComboBox  x:Name="comboBox"
                             Width="72"
                             LabelContent="_ComboBox Caption"
                             SelectedItem="{Binding ComboSelectedItem}"
                             ItemsSource="{Binding ComboSourceList}" />
```

However, I looked into making a custom control and there is a **daunting** amount of styling that is needed.

Is there a way to take what I have above and end up doing something like this?

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label Content="{Binding TemplateLabelContent}" 
           Target="{Binding ControlName}" 
           Margin="0" 
           Padding="5,5,5,1" />

    <InheritedComboBoxStuff/>

</StackPanel>
```

I know that will not work.  But my point is that is seems silly that I have to re-style the whole ComboBox just to add a label above it.

Comment: Have you looked at UserControls? Little styling required, just setting up the DP properties.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - the problem there (as I understand it) is that I have to re-expose all the properties of a ComboBox.  If that is so, I guess I just have to choose the lesser of the two evils.

Comment: It's just that you didn't mention all options. ControlTemplate, UserCOntrol and CustomControl. I think @Sebastian's answer is worth a try.

Answer (score 8):

You can make a template for that

```
  <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboWithHeader" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Margin="0"
                   Content="{Binding ComboBoxHeader}"
                   DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}"
                   Padding="5,5,5,1"
                   Target="comboBox" />

            <ComboBox x:Name="comboBox"
                      Width="72"
                      Margin="5,0,5,5"
                      DataContext="{TemplateBinding DataContext}"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ComboSourceList}"
                      Padding="5,1,5,5"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding ComboSelectedItem}" />
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
```

And then whenever you want to use combo with header, just use

```
<ContentControl Template="{StaticResource ComboWithHeader}" DataContext="{Binding ComboBoxViewModel}" />
```

Comment: Can this approach be used with two instances of it (with different label)?  It seems this would just make the same combobox/header combo over and over.  Is there a way to bind the Label.Content, ComboBox.SelecteItem and ComboBox.ItemsSource at the ContentControl level?

Comment: I assume you use MVVM pattern, datacontext of ContentControl will determine what will be itemsource and selected item of the combobox.
Label content should also be taken from ViewModel.
Instance of ComboBoxViewModel should contain properties { ComboSourceList, ComboSelectedItem, ComboBoxHeader}. So you can differentiate items in your control based on the viewmodel you pass as DataContext

Comment: Ok, that will work.  It is not what I would like, but it will work.  (Having to create a Separate ViewModel for each instance of my ComboBoxHeader is a bit verbose.)

Comment: If you dont like to pass combo header from viewmodel, just bind Label content to content of the content control :)
   <Label Margin="0"
                       Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                       Padding="5,5,5,1" />
And use it 
<ContentControl Content="My header" Template="{StaticResource ComboWithHeader}" DataContext="{Binding ComboBoxViewModel}" />

Answer (score 0):

Really basic but oh so simple, you can also create a UserControl, and then embed your control anywhere you want to as well. 
e.g.

[image: SimpleGraph]

```
<UserControl x:Class="xxx.View.TestResultsGraph"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" mc:Ignorable="d" 
         MinHeight="50"
         d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="300" >

    <Canvas Name="canvas" >
        <Polygon x:Name="SuccessShape" Fill="#FFF0FFF0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"   />
        <Polyline x:Name="SuccessLine" Stroke="Green"    StrokeThickness="0.5" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"   />
        <Polygon x:Name="FailShape" Fill="#FFFFF0F0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"   />
        <Polyline x:Name="FailLine" Stroke="Red"  StrokeThickness="0.5" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"      />
        <Polygon x:Name="PendingShape" Fill="#FFFFF0E0" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"   />
        <Polyline x:Name="PendingLine" Stroke="DarkOrange" StrokeThickness="0.5" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"    />
        <Line x:Name="xAxis" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  />
        <Line x:Name="yAxis" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="0.5" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" />
    </Canvas>
```