# Combining commonly used WPF-Controls for Reuse

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I keep repeating the same code over and over:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Label Content="Content 1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
        <ComboBox Style="{StaticResource CustomComboBox}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

It is always some combination of an Input-Control (TextBox, ComboBox, ...) and a Label.

I have scouted [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12590449/easy-way-to-add-a-label-to-the-wpf-combobox-control) Thread, but unfortunately the second answer relies on Bindings; I'd like to define the Content of the Label and the ComboBox-Bindings inside e.g. the ContentControl.

My attempt looks like this (inside MainWindow.xaml):

```
<Window.Resources>
    
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ComboWithHeader" TargetType="ContentControl">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Width="120" Height="25" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/> 
            <ComboBox Width="120" Height="25"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </ControlTemplate>
    
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="My Header" Template="{StaticResource ComboWithHeader}"/>
    
</Grid>
```

However, I couldn't set the Content, nor does it look quite appealing.
The ContentControl occupies the whole Window, and Content isn't visible.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ContentControl` should use a `ContentTemplate`:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ComboWithHeader">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
            <Label Width="120" Height="25" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            <ComboBox Width="120" Height="25"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <ContentControl Content="My Header" ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ComboWithHeader}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This worked, but interestingly Intellisense didn't recognize the ContentTemplate. When I typed it out, it worked nonetheless.

Comment: How would I add a TemplateBinding for the ItemsSource of the ComboBox? I might have to add a binding in the future.

Comment: Then you should probably consider creating your own custom control since a `ContentControl` has no `ItemsSource` property that you can set.